# How should I properly use Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get one number from Yahoo Finance (http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL), Balance Sheet, Total Stockholder Equity. If I inspect the element I get this:

```
<span data-reactid=".1doxyl2xoso.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.0.2:1:$BALANCE_SHEET.0.0.$TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY.1:$0.0.0">119,355,000</span>
```

I would like to get, scrap the number: 119,355,000.

If I understand correctly, web page is coded in Java Script and I need to use Selenium to get to the desired number. My attempt (I'm complete beginner) is not working no matter what I do, Bellow are three of many attempts. I tried to use 'data-reactid' and few other tings and I'm running out of ideas :-)

```
elem = Browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY') 
elem = browser.find_elem_by_id('TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY')
```

Comment: Just so you know, there is a `yahoo-finance` python package. You shouldn't need to write your own scraper

Comment: cricket_007, I will look into it also, thank you for mentioned it, but as complete noob I will probably struggle with that one for another week or more. Here I'm now 'soooo' close to finally get the result. I just need that one line of code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your all locator looks like invalid, try using `find_element_by_css_selector` as below :-

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span[data-reactid *= 'TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY']")
```

Note: `find_element_by_partial_text` is use to locate only `a` with paritially match of text content not their attribute text and `find_element_by_id` is use to locate any element with their `id` attribute which will match exactly with passing value.

**Edited** :- There are more elements found with the provided locator, so you should try to find exact row of `Total Stockholder Equity` means `tr` element then find all their `td` elements as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL')
browser.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5) 

    try:
        #first try to find balance sheet link and click on it
        balanceSheet = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'Balance Sheet']")))
        balanceSheet.click() 

        #Now find the row element of Total Stockholder Equity
        totalStockRow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[data-reactid *= 'TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY']")))

        #Now find all the columns included with Total Stockholder Equity
        totalColumns = totalStockRow.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

        #Now if you want to print single value just pass the index into totalColumns other wise print all values in the loop

        #Now print all values in the loop
        for elem in totalColumns:
             print elem.text
             #it will print value as 
             #Total Stockholder Equity
             #119,355,000
             #111,547,000
             #123,549,000
    except:
        print('Was not able to find the element with that name.')
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know which is proper selector, locator for this job. I think I tried them all but not with proper syntax. May I ask you one more thing? I'm using code from book: Automate Boring Stuff and original code works, but I'm unable to get TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY from the Yahoo site. Here is my short code with your correction: Ups I'm out of characters I will post code in next msg

Comment: @AL As I'm seeing in your provided website there are more than one element with the locator `span[data-reactid *= 'TOTAL_STOCKHOLDER_EQUITY']`. So it will always give you first one..

Comment: Yes I used your code but it still triggers exception. I must have done some other mistake. But original code works. Only Yahoo is causing problems, probably because of Java Script. Code is really short and I just posted whole if is OK for you to check it out on your computer? No hurry, though.

Comment: @Al_ Ok I have provided you working example with edited answer, try it and let me know..:)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, you made my day!!! I had to change code a little bit, wait was not used, so I searched internet and I changed **Wait** to **WebDriverWait** and it still didn't click on Balance Sheet until I changed to this:  **balanceSheet = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)** and now it is working and I have learned a lot and I can now start working on my project and learning to code in the process. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Al_ you welcome. Glad to help you..Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well if it helped...:)