# Pulling Income Statement Data using Python

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to pull data from Yahoo Finance using the below code but it is throwing me error.

I tried to debug from my end and it looks the title is coming as blank when using the find command

title = soup.find("strong", text=pattern) #returning blank

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""
#Read income statement to calculate ratios

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re,sys

myurl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&annual"
html = requests.get(myurl).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

def periodic_figure_values(soup, yahoo_figure):

    values = []
    pattern = re.compile(yahoo_figure)

    title = soup.find("strong", text=pattern)    # works for the figures printed in bold
    if title:
        row = title.parent.parent
    else:
        title = soup.find("td", text=pattern)    # works for any other available figure
        if title:
            row = title.parent
        else:
            sys.exit("Invalid figure '" + yahoo_figure + "' passed.")

    cells = row.find_all("td")[1:]    # exclude the <td> with figure name
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.text.strip() != yahoo_figure:    # needed because some figures are indented
            str_value = cell.text.strip().replace(",", "").replace("(", "-").replace(")", "")
            if str_value == "-":
                str_value = 0
            value = int(str_value) * 1000
            values.append(value)

    return values


def financials_soup(ticker_symbol, statement="is", quarterly=False):

    if statement == "is" or statement == "bs" or statement == "cf":
        url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/q/" + statement + "?s=" + ticker_symbol
        if not quarterly:
            url += "&annual"
        return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

    return sys.exit("Invalid financial statement code '" + statement + "' passed.")

print(periodic_figure_values(financials_soup("AAPL", "is"), "Income Tax Expense")) 

"""throws error: An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: Invalid figure 'Income Tax Expense' passed."""
```

Comment: Have you considered using Quandl instead? (FWIW, I'm not affiliated with any of these companies)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out (I'm just staring, complete noob), Yahoo finance uses Java Script. And as such, Beautiful Soup will not work. At least this is what I was told. Selenium should be correct tool for sites like this.

Here bellow is the link, where I asked similar question and in that link is code that works. Well almost. I had to change 2-3 small, trivial things:

[How should I properly use Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732496/how-should-i-properly-use-selenium)

Here is my comment, response what I changed to make it work: (not sure if code was later changed to reflect this, see if it is working for you without changing it, if not implement changes I did:

I had to change code a little bit, wait was not used, so I searched internet and I changed Wait to WebDriverWait and it still didn't click on Balance Sheet until I changed to this: balanceSheet = WebDriverWait(browser, 5) and now it is working and I have learned a lot and I can now start working on my project and learning to code in the process. Thank you so much! – Al_ Aug 3 at 13:07

---

Edit, my example only download one thing from Balance Sheet, but this should help you figure out how to do it for your case (Financial Statement). If you can't get code to work, I will send you my working code once I'm back at that computer.